# R:: Ftable to Usable data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, survey

I'm working with survey data and want to make a more usable data frame from a f-table but can't find any clear transformations.

The f-table (x) data looks like this, this is the survey procedure output.

```
library(survey)
design <- svydesign(id=~SDMVPSU, strata=~SDMVSTRA, weights=~WTMEC2YR, nest=TRUE,data=nhanes)

a <-  svyby(~factor(HI_CHOL), ~agecat, design, svymean, na.rm=TRUE ,quantiles=0.5,ci=TRUE,vartype=c(lowci="ci",hi="ci"), keep.names=TRUE)

x <- ftable(a)
```

[image]

Using data.frame(x) I get something like this:

[image]

I'd ideally like something cleaner, with columns like.

Sex, Smoking_status, Mean, Lower_CI, Upper_CI

Thanks for any help or direction. Either I'm missing something simple or way off.

Comment: Why not illustrate with a data object in survey package?

Comment: I'm not totally understanding what your saying. Is that an option in the package?

Comment: I don't know if it's easy or difficult. I only know at this point that `brf` is not in the datasets available in pkg:survey.

Comment: Oh I get you, let me re-work this question so everyone can use it.

Comment: `data(HairEyeColor)` could be an example. It is a "table" class already. This output is clean: `data.frame(ftable(formula= Hair ~ Eye + Sex, data=data.frame(HairEyeColor)))`. You should try the formula syntax in table`

Comment: Thanks, that is the ideal output I'd like. I still can't get the CI's to display correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be interested in [`ftable2df`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/ftable2df.R) from my [GitHub-only "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

Example `ftable`:

```
data(HairEyeColor)
ftable(HairEyeColor)
#             Sex Male Female
# Hair  Eye                  
# Black Brown       32     36
#       Blue        11      9
#       Hazel       10      5
#       Green        3      2
# Brown Brown       53     66
#       Blue        50     34
#       Hazel       25     29
#       Green       15     14
# Red   Brown       10     16
#       Blue        10      7
#       Hazel        7      7
#       Green        7      7
# Blond Brown        3      4
#       Blue        30     64
#       Hazel        5      5
#       Green        8      8
```

What `ftable2df` does:

```
library(SOfun)
ftable2df(ftable(HairEyeColor))
#     Hair   Eye Male Female
# 1  Black Brown   32     36
# 2  Black  Blue   11      9
# 3  Black Hazel   10      5
# 4  Black Green    3      2
# 5  Brown Brown   53     66
# 6  Brown  Blue   50     34
# 7  Brown Hazel   25     29
# 8  Brown Green   15     14
# 9    Red Brown   10     16
# 10   Red  Blue   10      7
# 11   Red Hazel    7      7
# 12   Red Green    7      7
# 13 Blond Brown    3      4
# 14 Blond  Blue   30     64
# 15 Blond Hazel    5      5
# 16 Blond Green    8      8
```

Answer (score 0):

from your comments, it looks like you just want this?

```
library(survey)
data(nhanes)
design <- svydesign(id=~SDMVPSU, strata=~SDMVSTRA, weights=~WTMEC2YR, nest=TRUE,data=nhanes)
a <-  svyby( ~ HI_CHOL , ~agecat + RIAGENDR + race , design, svymean, na.rm=TRUE ,vartype=c(lowci="ci",hi="ci") )
a
```

Comment: Sorry, haven't looked at this in a long time. I'll check it out today.